How to conditionally prevent the press of the navigation back button?
I have View A:
struct Dummy: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            NavigationLink(destination: ViewB()) {
                Image(systemName: "gear")   // placeholder systemname
                    .padding()
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                    .clipShape(.circle)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
        }
    }
}

and View B in which there's a text field with the binding value set to "" (empty string):
struct ViewB: View {
    @State private var name: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Your name is \(name)")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding()
                
                Divider()
                
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

What I want to do is to prevent the user from going back to View A by pressing the back button on the navigation bar in case the binding value name is empty. When the user starts typing so the value changes and gets set to something, the back button can be pressed again to go back.
I looked for a solution but found nothing.
I've tried using the .navigationBarBackButtonHidden() modifier but it only accepts a Bool and not a Binding\<Bool\>.

You can add your own back button using toolbar and dismiss. Also note that you only need 1 navigation stack

Thank you @loremipsum, I've used your solution and everything is working as intended.

First, you need to choose the correct navigation view:
From navigationBarBackButtonHidden(_:) documentation:

This modifier only takes effect when this view is inside of and visible within a NavigationView.

Second, you want the navigation bar to be hidden when the name is empty, so write accordingly:
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(name == "")

Personally, I prefer to write the equivalent:
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(name.isEmpty)

To conclude,ViewB will look like this:
struct ViewB: View {
    @State private var name: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { // <- Changed
            VStack {
                Text("Your name is \(name)")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding()
                
                Divider()
                
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(name.isEmpty)  // <- Added
    }
}


I've tried this and as I expected, since the navigationBarBackButtonHidden modifier takes a Bool and not a Binding value, I can change the value of name as much as I want but the back button gets hidden once the view refreshes. Thank you very much for the help.

My solution works fine. When nameis empty, there's no back button. Start to type, the button appears. Delete all characters, the button disappears. What else do you expect?
